# ASP.NET MVC: jQuery function works when placed in master page but not in view page - why?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, view

ASP.NET MVC.  When I place the simple jQuery function below in a master page, it works (i.e. an input with `id="cert-button"` is clicked and the user sees a confirmation message).  However, if I place it anywhere in the view page (.aspx), then it is not triggered.  Why could this be?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#cert-button").click(function () { return confirm("Continue?"); });
</script>
```

P.S. I've just started with JavaScript in MVC and it seems a bit haphazard whether something will work or not.  I'm starting to wonder if there's some kind of caching/initialization issue at play.

Comment: Is anything different about the element being referenced?  That is, does `#cert-button` still exist as before?  Also, you might try wrapping it in a `$(document).ready()` to make sure it's not trying to bind to the click event before the DOM is ready.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap that puppy up in the document ready!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#cert-button").click(function () { return confirm("Continue?"); });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it with a `ready` event, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ $("#cert-button").click(function () { return confirm("Continue?"); }); });
</script>
```

Comment: Works perfectly, down to the last semi-colon.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your button is placed after the script in the HTML, so it doesn't exist when you run the script.

As the other answers implies. You can avoid this by putting it inside `$(document).ready()`, so it waits until the DOM is loaded, before it attaches the click event.